# Php 7: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in

Tags: php, pdo

He estado aprendiendo de Php en un curso online que quizá muchos conoceran, impartido por Pildorasinformáticas. En este tema de *conexión a BBDDs con clases POO y PDO* me ha ocurrido un error que llevo días sin poder resolver.

Este pequeño programa de juguete trata sobre un buscador que va a una base de datos a pedir la información de algunos productos dependiendo del parámetro *país*. hay cuatro archivos en este pequeño programa:

*index.php*

```
<?php
require ('devuelve_productos.php');

$pais = $_GET["buscar"];

$productos = new DevuelveProductos(); #Aquí iniciamos todo, es como darle al botón del start

$array_productos = $productos->get_productos($pais);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Conexion con clases POO</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

    foreach($array_productos as $elemento){?>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['CÓDIGOARTÍCULO']?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['NOMBREARTÍCULO']?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['SECCIÓN']?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['PRECIO']?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['FECHA']?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['IMPORTADO']?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $elemento ['PAÍSDEORIGEN']?> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br><?php
    };
?>
```

*devuelve_productos.php*

```
<?php 

require 'conexion.php';

class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{

    public function DevuelveProductos(){

        parent::__construct(); #Aquí está llamando al cosntructor de la clase padre (o sea del archivo conexion). En conclusión, está conectando a la BBDD
    }

    public function get_productos($dato){

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PAÍSDEORIGEN = "' . $dato . '"';

        $sentencia = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

        $sentencia->execute(array());

        $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $sentencia->closeCursor();

        $this->conexion_db = null;

        return $resultado;


    }
}
?>
```

*conexion.php*

```
<?php

class Conexion{

    protected $conexion_db;

    public function Conexion(){

        try {

            $this->conexion_db = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost, db_name =pruebas', 'root', '');

            $this->conexion_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $this->conexion_db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

            return $this->conexion_db;

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " en la línea: " . $e->getLine();

        }finally{



        }

    }
}
?>
```

*formulario_busqueda_paises.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de búsqueda</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <label for="buscar">Introduzca país: <input type="text" name="buscar"></label>
        <input type="submit" name="enviando" value="¡Dale!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Al ejecutarse el archivo principal(formulario_busqueda_paises.php), este manda a llamar a *index.php* para que este devuelva los resultados de la búsqueda.

cuando yo ejecuto el archivo *formulario_busqueda_paises.php* y coloco el país que quiero buscar, me tira este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog
>   name: 1046 No database selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso
>   PHP\BBDD\Conexion_BBDD_clases_poo\usando_pdo\devuelve_productos.php:18
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso
>   PHP\BBDD\Conexion_BBDD_clases_poo\usando_pdo\devuelve_productos.php(18):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso
>   PHP\BBDD\Conexion_BBDD_clases_poo\usando_pdo\index.php(8):
>   DevuelveProductos->get_productos('Espa\xC3\xB1a') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso
>   PHP\BBDD\Conexion_BBDD_clases_poo\usando_pdo\devuelve_productos.php on
>   line 18

He revisado MILLONES de veces la línea 18, y hasta donde yo puedo ver no hay nada malo, he revisado MILLONES de veces el nombre de la base de datos y también está todo correcto, quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema por favor.

Muchas gracias de ante-mano

Comment: La selección de la base de datos no lleva **_**  , solo es `dbname=pruebas`

Comment: Pero esos mismos datos de conexión ocupé en otro archivo, y ese si me conectó de manera exitosa, por eso no entiendo porque aquí me da error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ya han comentado los compañeros en sus respuestas, estás pasando los datos de conexión de forma errónea.

Pero también tienes un error en el método `get_productos`: le pasas un array vacío en el `execute`. Y además ese código es altamente vulnerable a Inyección SQL, se trata de un grave problema de seguridad.

### Corrigiendo la conexión

Como podrás apreciar, voy a usar una variable `$arrOptions` para setear una configuración adecuada al objeto conexión que se creará. Con ese array, no hace falta hacer más configuraciones, una vez creado el objeto. Además, en PDO hay que desactivar siempre `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, de lo contrario, el driver emulará ciertas consultas y podrías tener una inyección SQL<sup>1</sup>.

```
/*Array con todo lo necesario para la configuración*/
    $arrOptions = array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
    );

    try {

        # Intentar la conexión 
        $this->conexion_db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=pruebas;host=localhost', 'root', '', $arrOptions);
        return $this->conexion_db;
        //Resto de tu código ...
```

---

### Corrigiendo la consulta en `get_productos`

```
public function get_productos($dato){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PAÍSDEORIGEN = ?';
    $sentencia = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->execute(array($dato));
    $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sentencia->closeCursor();
    $this->conexion_db = null;
    return $resultado;
}
```

Básicamente lo que se ha hecho ha sido:

- Cambiar la sentencia SQL, quitando el dato que pasabas directamente y cambiándolo por un marcador de posición `?`. Ejecutar una sentencia como la tienes en tu código es un agujero gravísimo... te pueden colar cualquier cosa.
- Pasar la variable `$dato` en un array en el `execute`. De ese modo, neutralizamos cualquier ataque malicioso.

Ya como sugerencia, yo nunca pondría tildes en nombres de columnas o tablas de la base de datos. Lo digo por esta columna: `PAÍSDEORIGEN`.

Espero te sirva.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Esto ha sido ampliamente explicado y demostrado [en mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967) a la pregunta: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)</sub>

Comment: ¿Que tan recomendable es que, en vez de '?' ocupe marcadores?

Comment: @DiegoSaravia puedes usar marcadores de `:nombre` en vez de marcadores de posicion (`?`). Tienen la ventaja de que el código queda más claro y menos propensos a errores, porque cada dato iría asociado a su marcador en el `execute` o en el `bindParam` o `bindValue`. Un poco tarde mi respuesta, espero sirva de todos modos.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que hay un error en el constructor de `PDO`, prueba modificándolo así:

```
$this->conexion_db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
```

He cambiado `db_name` por `dbname`, he quitado los espacios y cambiado la coma que habías puesto después de 'localhost'  por `;`