# Tengo un error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php7

**Hola, 

Buen Día/Tarde/Noche.** 


He estado aprendiendo un poco de PHP en línea con algunos cursos de Youtube, y estoy tratando de hacer un carrito de compra "e-commerce", pero en lo poco que llevo, tengo un error en mi código, lo he revisado de pies a cabeza y no veo cuál sea el error, ya que en lo que llevo sólo quiero que me arroje un print_r con los productos que metí en la base de datos.

Aquí dejo el poco avance de mi código para saber sí pueden ayudarme a encontrar la solución a mi problema.

Este es el de **config.php**

```
<?php
define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
define("USUARIO","root");
define("PASSWORD","contraseña");
define("BD","tienda");
?>
```

Este es el de **conexión.php**

```
<?php

$servidor = "mysql:host = ".SERVIDOR.";dbname = ".BD;

try{

    $pdo = new PDO($servidor,USUARIO,PASSWORD,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8")
);
     echo "<script>alert('Contectado..')</script>";

}catch(PDOException $e){
     
    echo "<script>alert('Error..')</script>"; 
}
?>
```

Y este es el **index.php**, en el cual solo esta los **include** de cada archivo, y en la parte la primera fila está el código que utilice, pero me da error.

```
    <?php
    include './global/config.php';
    include './global/conexion.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#my-nav" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="my-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="my-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Carrito <span class="sr-only">(0)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
    <br>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            ¡Bienvenidos a Title!
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-success">Ver carrito</a>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
    <?PHP
        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblproductos`");
        $sentencia->execute();
        $listaProductos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($listaProductos);
    ?>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" title="Título del Producto" alt="Título" src="./sources/img/Sudadera.jpg">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span>Título del Producto</span>
                    <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Content</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit">Agregar al Carrito</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Está es la línea que me causa error.

```
<?PHP
        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblproductos`");
        $sentencia->execute();
        $listaProductos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($listaProductos);
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes una base de datos llamada `tienda`?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Php 7: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE\[3D000\]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151455/php-7-uncaught-pdoexception-sqlstate3d000-invalid-catalog-name-1046-no-dat) Debes quitar los espacios en blanco en la definición del dsn: **`$servidor = "mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".BD;`**  y asegurarte de que tienes una base de datos llamada `tienda`.

Answer (score 2):

[Según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php), el DSN debe quedar así:

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba
```

**Sin espacios en blanco**.

Al crear `$servidor` estás poniendo espacios en blanco, y eso crea un DSN inválido:

```
$servidor = "mysql:host = ".SERVIDOR.";dbname = ".BD;
```

En caso de funcionar, le estarías diciendo que se conecta a una base de datos llamada

```
 tienda
^espacio
```

Y, no existe una BD llamada `[espacio]tienda`.

Si quitas los espacios en blanco y los demás datos son correctos, debería funcionar:

```
$servidor = "mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".BD;
```